# Save a loaded picture from firefox extension

Tags: javascript, image, firefox, dom, firefox-addon

From within my firefox extension I want to save a picture which is already loaded and shown in  a browser tab. I only found ways to download a file or picture directly from the server with a binary input stream passing the url of the picture. But this is not what I want to do here.

So, how can I save a picture which is already loaded by firefox to a local file?

Comment: @karthikrangaraj: The question is actually quite clear.

Comment: @Wladimir Palant:Ok, now I think I have understood this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file in your add-on and convert binary image data into base64 and dump that encoded data into that file.